# How to read ignored filename from config.json file

Tags: node.js, json, package.json, nodemon

I have a config file that I specify my database path in that:

```
{   
"runningPort": 3001,
"databasePath":"database.json",
}
```

The problem is that I use Nodemon and I want to ignore my database file when using it.
my script in package.json is Like this:

```
{
...,
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon --ignore database.json start.js"
  },
...
}
```

what I want is to read **database.json** from **config.json** file so that just by changing **databasePath** in config.json file I can change the targeted database.

Comment: `databasePath in config.json file I can change the targeted database.` when you say this - it means writing new `databasePath` to the config.json?

Comment: No I mean just by changing dataPath field in config.json the ignored file fore nodemon is changed to.

Comment: When do you want to change it, on the runtime?

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/config and switch different config by NODE_ENV or NODE_CONFIG_ENV variable

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara No before running my serverside code.